# Java, moving robot

Tags: java

Method pickUpNBeepersCheckIfAll() that takes an integer parameter, and makes the most recently created robot pick up that number of beepers from the beeper stack at its current location.
You can assume that there are enough beepers in the stack for the robot to do this safely.
The method should return true if the robot has picked up all the beepers at its current location, or false if there are still beepers on the ground.

My method:

```
boolean pickUpNBeepersCheckIfAll(int beeper) {
    int counter=0;
        while(beeper>counter) {
            pickUpItemWithRobot(); 
            counter++;
            beeper--;
            if(beeper==0) return true;
        } 
     return false;
   }
```

Here is my code, and I can't find a mistake, because there are four outcomes:
pick Up Random Beepers (not all), pick up one beeper, pick up 10 beepers and pick up zero beepers. SO here I have 2 mistakes here.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: should you be decrementing `beeper` and incrementing `counter` in the same iteration...? idk that just doesn't seem quite right

Comment: While I don't really understand what you're asking, I'm pretty sure the problem is that the "counter" variable shouldn't exist. Your loop condition should be `while (beeper > 0)`

Comment: `and I can't find a mistake` that means your code is correct right?

Comment: "SO here I have 2 mistakes here." What are they? How is this method being called? What are the desired vs. actual outputs?

Comment: [SO is not for code dumps](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88842/discourage-code-dumps). Please describe your problem, steps you've taken to try solving it, etc.

Comment: what's `counter` for?  do you intend to only pick up half of the `beeper`s?

Comment: Maybe you need a [for loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I think I see where you are failing.

Basically, the pile of beepers is *different* from the number of beepers that you want to pick up. You are treating them as the same thing.

I am also confused why you have a counter. You don't need to know how many beepers you picked up -- You are always going to be picking up the same number that you take in. The only thing you are concerned with is whether or not there are any beepers left after you have picked all of them up.

What I would do (based on your code and the problem)

```
boolean pickUpNBeepersCheckIfAll(int beeper) {
     for(int x = 0; x < beeper; x++)
         pickUpItemWithRobot();
         beeperStack--;
     }
     if(beeperStack > 0)
     {
         return false;
     }
     return true;
   }
```

where beeperStack is the global pre-defined variable that contains the number of beepers that are inside of this particular stack.

edit: I would also keep in mind that we need more information than "It doesn't work!". Knowing what pickupItemWithRobot() does would help, among other things.